# Slicing a Multidimensional NumPy Array with IF condition

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, slice

I am new to python and I'm trying to write a function to slice a multidimensional numpy array. There are several requirements:

1. return the element of array a if both i and j are not None values,
2. return row i of array a if i is not a None value but j is None.
3. return column j of array a if j is not a None value but i is None.

-

```
def function(a,j,i):
    if i is not None and j is not None:
        return a
    elif i is not None and j is None:
        return a[i-1]
    elif i is None and j is not None:
        return a[:,j-1]
```

I'm doing this right now but got an error says ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I don't think this code is the source of the bug (but it has it's problems). Post the whole code, i.e. where/how you use `function` function.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me but you probably can just do this:

```
def function(a,j,i):
    return a[i, j] # None is treated as : in np, so no need to filter for it.
```

This will get what you wanted..

Also, there's a bug in your logic:

```
if i is not None and j is not None:
    return a
```

Do you mean

```
if i is None and j is None:
    return a
```